# HTML form gives file not found error when submitting

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to set up a basic HTML form for an assignment in my web design class, but when I fill out the form and submit in my web browser, it gives a file not found error. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong since I'm basically just following what the instructor's directions say. Any help is greatly appreciated, sorry for any posting mistakes, first time user.

```js
function display() {
  DispWin = window.open('', 'NewWin', 'toolbar=no,status=no,width=300,height=200')
  message = "<ul><li><b>First Name: </b>" + document.test.firstname.value;
  message += "<li><b>Last Name: </b>" + document.test.lastname.value;
  message += "<li><b>E-Mail: </b>" + document.test.email.value;
  message += "<li><b>Understanding Level: </b>" + document.test.understanding.value;
  message += "<li><b>Pass/Fail: </b>" + document.test.passfail.value;
  message += "<li><b>Comments: </b>" + document.test.comments.value + "</ul>";
  DispWin.document.write(message);
}
```

```html
<p>HTML Forms Test</p>
<form name=”test” method=”post” action=”index.html”>
  <p>
    <label>First Name: </label><input type="text" name="first" id="firstname">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Last Name: </label><input type="text" name="last" id="lastname">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>E-Mail: </label><input type="text" name="email" id="email">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>How well do you understand HTML code? (1-10) </label><input type="range" name="understanding" id="understanding" min="1" max="10" value="5">
  </p>
  <p>
    How do you think you'll do in this class?
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="passfail" value="pass" id="passfail_0"> <label>Pass </label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="passfail" value="fail" id="passfail_1"> <label>Fail </label>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Comments: </label><textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="display();">
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved, this line `<form name=”test” method=”post” action=”index.html”>` has smart quotes and not regular quotation marks.